# When I apply safe args plugin ( apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin" ) in android , show the below ERROR

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression cannot be cast to org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression
org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression cannot be cast to org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

enter code here

**After restarting or rebuild the Error steel appears.**

Comment: That sounds like an issue with Android Studio. Are you already using the latest version? Probably best to [file an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192708&template=840533) if upgrading to the latest version doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Put app / module in build In the gradle file, if your plugins are like this:
plugins `{ id plugin: 'com.android.application'}`

Change to: `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`。